# Disk Partitioning - Can't create partition

Tags: partition, disk

I've been following this example to restore capacity to my microSD --> [SD card corrupt and stuck at 32MB, any way to fix it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/sd-card-corrupt-and-stuck-at-32mb-any-way-to-fix-it)

Everything seems to work until I get to

```
mkfs /dev/sdx1
```

It tells me there no such file or directory. If I go to my /dev directory it never created sdx1. I've tried several methods but nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: `x` is a placeholder. You need to use the actual letter Linux assigned. `dmesg` or `lsblk` or `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id` to try to find it.

Comment: I know I was using sdg1 which corresponds to mine

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/sdg`, then?

Comment: Type `lsblk` to list all of the block devices on your system.

Comment: if you knew device name i.e `/dev/sdg1`  then you can use `mkfs /dev/sdg1`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the first partition of this device. Since you say it is corrupted, the partition table is corrupted, too. So your system only recognizes the device /dev/sdx but not partitions sdx1, sdx2, etc. Try `fdisk /dev/sdx`, `cfdisk /dev/sdx` or `parted /dev/sdx` to check the partition table.

Comment: That may be the scenario but I followed the steps to create a new partition table. This partition table should not be corrupted. Why the new sdg1 is never created is what my question is.